# How to substitute in an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to solve this integral by substitution:

$$ \int \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}\,dx $$

I know the substitution should be:

$$ u= \sqrt x$$ and so $$du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$$

but i can't understand how i should put this values in my integral! I would like to understand how to replace correctly.

Comment: Did you mean $\dfrac{1}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}$?

Comment: Don't put the $dx$ in the denominator. It is meaningless in the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to write the $dx$:
$$\int \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}dx$$
and remember to write the $dx$:
$$du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}dx$$
Now, we have $dx$ in the original integral, so we want to substitute an expression in terms of $u$ for $dx$, so we solve for $dx$:
$$dx=2\sqrt x \ du=2u \ du$$
Thus, by substituting this into the integral, we get:
$$\int \frac{1}{(1+u)^2}2u \ du$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $2 u du=dx$, we have:
$\int{\frac{2u}{(u+1)^2}du}=\int{\frac{2u+2-2}{(u+1)^2}du}=2\int{\frac{du}{u+1}}-2\int{\frac{du}{(u+1)^2}}=2\ln{(u+1)}+\frac{2}{u+1}+C$